# How to auto-scroll images horizontally in responsive design

Tags: javascript, css, image, scroll, responsive-design

So i have this site: http://onthemouse.com/. I have my portfolio images in a grid like formation using the `<li>` tag on the front page. I need them to align side by side and scroll horizontally automatically, maybe using javascript or jquery (no other libraries, please). It's fine if it has a scrollbar as well. I've tried something like this:

```
.portfolio li {
  width: 438px !important;
  display:inline !important;
}
```

and then

```
<ul id="thumbs" style="width:100%;list-style:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap;">
    <li class="portfolio" style="width: 438px; opacity: 1;display:inline;">
      <a href="BLAHBLAH" title="BLAHBLAH">
        <img src="BLAHBLAH" alt="" title="" >
      </a>
    </li>
```

that's basically just a stripped down version if you vist the page theres a lot more tags associated. but even this code alone (with all the tags closed obviously) didn't seem to work..

Comment: What do you need? Your images already are placed side by side

Comment: i need them to scroll horizontally, without going on to the next line, so that i have a ton of space left on the bottom.

Comment: Actually, what you want is not a responsive design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using Flexislider for your problem here. It's a responsive slider.

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 1):

remove `display:inline`, `width` from `style` attr of your `li`

```
<ul id="thumbs" style="list-style:none;">
<li class="portfolio" style="opacity: 1;">
  <a href="BLAHBLAH" title="BLAHBLAH">
    <img src="BLAHBLAH" alt="" title="" >
  </a>
</li>



#works, #wrapper {
    overflow: visible;
}
body {
    overflow-x:auto;
}
#thumbs .portfolio {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 438px !important;
    float:none !important;
}
#thumbs {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
/* for ie 7*/
*:first-child+html #thumbs .thumb {
    display:inline;
    zoom:1;
}
/* for ie 6*/
*html #thumbs .thumb {
    display:inline;
    zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: i tried it in dreamweaver, doesn't seem to work, could you show me a fiddle with two <li>s in the list so i can see. when i did it they just showed on top of each other.

Comment: set `float: none !important;` on `.portfolio;` or remove `float:left` from `.thumb`

Comment: thanks man, but it seems to be working with answer above, so i'ma go with that, but thanks anyway man.